# Adding resource to form breaks designer, c# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

My `InitializeComponent` method:

```cs
ResourceManager rm = Resources.ResourceManager;
...
this.tsbAdd.Image = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("add");
```

Program as a whole works flawlessly, but i cannot open designer now. Which is weird, because i'm pretty sure it worked before. Either way, this is the error i get now:

```
The variable 'rm' is either undeclared or was never assigned.
```

Which is false, because it is clearly declared, and has been used multiple times. 
I can just comment it every time i want to open designer, but its pretty annoying, because comments are quickly removed in that method by compiler.

Comment: What version of Visual Studios are you using? Are your component compiled in x64?

Comment: I haven't updated in probably a month. And not sure is it compiled in x64. It should be though, i should be using VS x64.

Comment: Is this code in form.designer.cs?

Comment: @OguzOzgul yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An examination of the stack trace for the error shows that the Visual Studio Designer while displaying the form in design mode parses this designer.cs file **line by line**, and not executing it.

This will fix your problem, but as you know, you should not put anything in the designer and as soon as you make the slightest change to the form in design mode or change any of the properties of any control on your form using the editor, this line of yours will be gone.

```
//ResourceManager rm = Resources.ResourceManager;
//...
this.tsbAdd.Image = (Bitmap)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("add");
```

Adding the same code in the constructor of the form will work too,

I recommend moving your code inside the form constructor, right after InitializeComponent() call.

```
ResourceManager rm = Resources.ResourceManager;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.tsbAdd.Image = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("add");
}
```

Comment: Ok, this one works. I would honestly prefer keeping Form settings in Designer.cs, but since it won't let me i'm forced to use that one. Thanks for help.

Comment: You can actually, if you set the image of the control using the editor and properties window. It will then be put inside designer.cs and will not be removed. I thought you cannot do this for some reason. This is just a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

One possible quick fix is cleaning and then rebuilding your solution.

Under `Build` tab in Visual Studios or right click on your solution shown in the solution explorer

1. Clean solution
2. Rebuild solution
3. Restart Visual Studios

If this does not work make sure your have the call to `InitializeComponent` as the first row in the constructor of your class.

Comment: Nothing changed. ```InitializeComponent``` is first.